# continuous integration and visual studio references to projects with static version number

Tags: visual-studio

One project I would like to add to a build server has version numbers explicitely hardcoded in the project web.config file.
The project referenced is part of the same solution.
When building I use a msbuild FileUpdate (MSBuild.Community.Tasks) function to update revision numbers in assembly files - problem is that the version number is still referenced in my webconfig file so the project is not able to find the referenced file as the versions do not match any longer.
at are my options to update the webconfig file automaticallly on build server? I would prefer avoiding the regex in that case to avoid any unexpected impact on the file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a really bad idea. What are you doing with the version number from web.config anyway? Can you store it in a separate file, like `Version.txt` or something?

Updating the web.config on the server every time you deploy is madness. At the very least it will probably cause the app-pool to be recycled unnecessarily.

---

**Edit 1**: wait, are you talking about version numbers (like `v1.0.0.123`) or the assembly binding redirect thing (like `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>`)?

---

**Edit 2**: sorry I thought you meant something else. In this case you have no choice but to update your web.config with the new assembly version numbers.

Comment: Thanks for reading - for example 

    <add assembly="X.MySubProject, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e887d47c090832ef"
    Namespace="X" %>

If my subproject is built at the time than the parent project, then the parent can import it as the version changed.. Incompatible with continuous integration.